# change image on click

Tags: jquery, image

I have several images and radio buttons in a table. i want the image to change depending on the radio button that a user clicks.

I am able to change the Image. The problem is that i don't know how to change the image back if a user clicks another button on the table.

below is my code:

```
function changeImage(){
            var descriptionValue = Math.round( $("input[type='radio']:checked").val());
        switch(descriptionValue)
        {
          case 25:
            $("#twentyfive").attr('src',"/images1.gif");
          break;
          case 30:
            $("#thirty").attr('src',"/images2.gif");
          break;
          case 50:
             $("#fifty").attr('src',"/image3.gif");
          break;
          case 80:
             $("#eighty").attr('src',"/image4.gif");
          break;
        }
    };
```

**HTML**

```
<table  border="0" cellpadding="0" align="center">
    <tr>

        <td height="90">    
            <input type="radio" value="25.00">
            <img id="twentyfive" src="aimage1.gif" />
        <td>    
            <input type="radio"  value="30.00">
            <img  id="thirty"  src="aimage2.gif"  />
        </td>
        <td>    
            <input type="radio" value="50.00">
            <img id="fifty"  src="images3.gif" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="3" align="center">    
            <input type="radio"  value="80.00">
            <img  id="eighty"  src="aimages4.gif" />
        </td>
    </tr>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Comment: What do you mean "change the image back"?

Comment: you can use a `default:` in your `switch` so if it isn't one of the values, then it defaults to another image.  Also you seem to be changing the sources of different images - surely you justwant to change the source of the same image (or show / hide the different images)

Comment: Please show your HTML - we can't see what buttons you mean

Comment: hi guys. thanks for response.as you can see from code. i am able to change the images depending on what radio button a user clicks. the issue is when the user then clicks another button;; the first image that was click needs to revert to original image

Comment: You question needs editing. You are not conveying enough information to get help

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to tell based on the info you've provided.

instead of using that switch statement, Why don't you store the images in an object, like this:

```
var images = [
    {
        value: 25,
        defaultImage: "aimage1.gif",
        newImage: "/images1.gif"
    },
    {
        value: 30,
        defaultImage: "/images2.gif",
        newImage: "/images2.gif"
    }

];
```

etc. etc.

Then you could write a method like to restore your default image and attach it to the click event in the following fashion.

```
$('table').on('click', function(){
    $('table').children().restoreDefault();
    $(this).changeImage()
});
```

Comment: hi. thank you for the answer. i am not quite sure how u mean a restroeDefault() object. do u have a sample

Comment: I can't write the function for you right now, but I elaborated a little bit more on how to use an object method to accomplish what you are trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

You need to save the current image source, For which you can use the `data()` method. Try something along:

```
function changeImage(){
    $("img").each(function(){
       var originalSrc = $(this).data("initial");
       if(originalSrc)
        $(this).attr("src",originalSrc)
    });
    var descriptionValue = Math.round( $("input[type='radio']:checked").val());
    switch(descriptionValue)
    {
      case 25:
        var src = $("#twentyfive").attr("src");
        $("#twentyfive").data("initial",src).attr('src',"/images1.gif");
      break;
      case 30:
        var src = $("#thirty").attr("src");
        $("#thirty").data("initial",src).attr('src',"/images2.gif");
      break;
      case 50:
         var src = $("#fifty").attr("src");
         $("#fifty").data("initial",src).attr('src',"/image3.gif");
      break;
      case 80:
         var src = $("#eighty").attr("src");
         $("#eighty").data("initial",src).attr('src',"/image4.gif");
      break;
    }
};
```